# Assembly Lang: How to remove the 'enter' key / 'note' symbol 'variables'

Tags: string, assembly, ascii, buffer

We are assigned to find a way to remove the *'enter'* symbol, denoted by the *'note'* symbol from the buffer in assembly language.

Let me elaborate...

Below is the given code that we have to revise:

```
.MODEL small 
.DATA
BUFFER DB 30 DUP(?)

.CODE   
MAIN PROC 
    MOV AX,@DATA
    MOV DS,AX  
    MOV BX,OFFSET BUFFER
 HERE:    
  
    ;read a char from the keyboard
    MOV AH,1
    INT 21H 

    MOV [BX],AL 
    INC BX
    CMP AL,13
    JNE HERE
    
    MOV [BX],'$' 
    
    MOV DH, 10 ; Row 10
    MOV DL, 20 ; Column 20
    MOV BH, 0 ; Page 0
    MOV AH, 2
    INT 10H 
    
    MOV DX,OFFSET BUFFER
    MOV AH,9
    INT 21H
   
    
    ; wait for any key....    
    MOV AH, 1
    INT 21H
    
    MOV AX,4c00h ; exit to operating system.
    INT 21h    
MAIN ENDP
END MAIN
```

In the code above, I have assigned a size of 30 in the buffer. After entering a string, press the *'enter'* key to stop taking input and print the string.

Again, the problem is, the *'enter'* key is detected as a character under the ASCII code, and after running the code, and checking the variables(vars), you will see a *'note'* symbol, which is what I wanted to remove.

[image]

I could just:

```
DEC BX
```

to make the code one step back, but that just makes the *'dollar'* sign be on top of the *'note'* symbol.

**I'm really stumpped here, any help would be apreciated**

Comment: It's unclear what your problem is. What do you mean by "on top of the note symbol". Don't you want to overwrite the enter with the dollar? What result do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Jester My prof said that the result of the possible solution I said, will only stack the dollar and note in the same memory cell. Basically I want the out put to be 'M', 'A', 'R', 'I', 'A', '$', NULL, NULL...

Comment: You can't have both in the same byte. If you put the `$` in there, it will overwrite the note symbol. So that should work. If you also need a `NULL` in the place where the `$` was you need to put it there yourself.